# /opt not found at Home in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, xampp

I tried to install XAMPP to opt directory using this command:

```
sudo tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.8.0.tar.gz -C /opt
```

But, there is no folder there named `/opt` when I searched for this folder, there was a folder named `/opt` under `/etc` and another folder under `/inode`. So, where I can install XAMPP now - in the `etc/opt/` or to create a directory named `/opt` in Home?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create opt folder and install in it

```
 sudo mkdir /opt
```

and then

```
 sudo tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.8.0.tar.gz -C /opt
```

**opt**

It holds optional software and packages that you install that are not required for the system to run.

Opt is reserved for additional software you install; although, most providers don’t use it. This is kind of like ‘Program Files‘ for linux.

Sources

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649355/what-does-opt-mean-as-in-the-opt-directory-is-it-an-abbreviation

http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_beginner_books/linux_filesystem/opt.html

http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/understanding-the-linux-directory-layout/

Answer (score 0):

**cek in here full tutorial**

How To Install Xampp 1.8.1 in Linux Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail

How To Resolve Error PhpMyadmin Forbidden XAMPP

http://www.ubuntukiller.com/2013/05/how-to-install-xampp-181-in-linux.html